# access violation on clientmoduleunit.pas on client side

Tags: delphi, datasnap

Well in my datasnap app on the client side i have obviously a clientmodule. I get an error on closing my application:

[ERROR](http://i1187.photobucket.com/albums/z387/giulichajari/Dibujo_zpsded4oier.jpg)
According to the debugger is in this funtion:

```
destructor TClientModule1.Destroy;
 begin
  FServerMethods1Client.Free;
  inherited;
 end;
```

compiller show this:

First chance exception at $0059ABC4. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0059abc4: read of address 0x00000034'. Process Cajero.exe (1856)

Comment: Most likely that `FServerMethods1Client` was freed before this destructor executes.  More code would help.  Where is `FServerMethods1Client` created?  Do you call `Free` on it anywhere else?  Also, if you have error messages, please copy the *text* of the message and [edit] your question to include it.  Pictures of errors hosted off-site are not useful.

Comment: but there is no other instruction related with this or which can freed FserverMethodsClient

Comment: Do you know what an access violation is? If not then you should learn. With that knowledge you'd be able to identify the fault. Also, when you ask a question about an error, you should include the error message verbatim. It's not visible here.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a call stack.  There is not enough information here to diagnose the problem.  You have a `nil` object reference somewhere.  You need to do some debugging to find where it is.

Comment: https://github.com/giulichajari/error-access-violation/issues/1 here is the code of datamodule

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Try change the ServerMethods1Client to a readonly property, and then the compiler wil tell you where your bug is. Thats 5 minutes of work.

Comment: I create a breakpoint and it says FServerMethods1Client is null when executing this:  FServerMethods1Client.Free;

Comment: @user3780282 make you property readonly and you'll see whats wrong. And about the fact FServerMethods1Client is null seval people told you all ready. But so far you refuse to react on it.

Comment: @user3780282 If `FserverMethods1Client` is `nil` then `Free` will not do anything - `Free` checks for `nil` before calling `Destroy`.  From that breakpoint, push F7 and keep going.

Comment: Never mind. You refuse to debug. Your loss.

Comment: If you refuse to attempt to understand the concepts you will be doomed to ask a question every time you make such a mistake. If you knew what an access violation was you would not have asked this question.

Comment: also: when i close embarcadero XE2 it says access violation at "midas.dll"

Comment: It's almost as if you are ignoring what we say

Answer (score 0):

According to you Screenshot you get an AV at a low adress $34 that indicates that you are caling methods on an object reference that is nil.

Try this dummy code

```
procedure TForm22.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TForm(nil).Next;
end;
```

And have a look at the adress at the AV.

When you try to call a method on a object, the compiler looks in a table called VMT to find trhe offset of the method. This value is added to the adress of the object reference.

In your code you have a `property`  called `ServerMethods1Client` which is defined like this:

```
property ServerMethods1Client: TServerMethods1Client read GetServerMethods1Client write FServerMethods1Client;
```

Try change it to a readonly property

```
property ServerMethods1Client: TServerMethods1Client read GetServerMethods1Client;
```

Then the compiler will tell you where you are assiging a nil value to you property.

Comment: VMT only used for virtual methods

Comment: Is in the same line.. at the "end;" of destructor method. I write the event OnCreate of datamodule, i suppose it has something at respect..

Comment: i can't help you. You are not responding to the advice given .